# Thread does not exit when a form is closed while other forms are hidden

Tags: c#, .net, forms, winforms

The following code successfully calls another form, Shows it, hides the first one and repeats the same process for Form2. (There are 3 forms in total).
But if someone closes the app using the X in the middle of the application. (In Form2 or Form3), the application keeps running in the background and I have to manually terminate it using the task manager.

I am a student so my code is probably fairly unoptimized, but despite looking for an answer on the internet I could not find a solution.

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FormSurveyOpdracht
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //When Next button is clicked:
        {
           //Rest of the Code

            Form2 form2 = new Form2(fullname);                  //Define a new form Form2, and send the variable fullname.
            form2.Show();                                       //Show the Form2.
            this.Hide();                                        //Hide this Form (Form1)
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) //if the form is closed in an unexpected way, exit the whole application.
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

What I tried: I tried to close the application using the X.
I was expecting: The whole application to close.
What happened: The application kept running in the background.

What else I tried: I tried putting a

```
   private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) //if the form is closed in an unexpected way, exit the whole application.
   {
       Application.Exit();
   }
```

on each form (Form1 for form1, Form2 for form2 etc.)
What happened: The application keeps running.
I also tried: Application.ExitThread(); and Environment.Exit(0); Does not work.

Comment: Try adding to bind this event to the form before opening it `form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();`. NOTE you need to do this for every form you open so for form 3 it would be `form3.closed` etc

Comment: Should i do `Form2 form2 = new Form2(fullname);` `form2.Closed += (s, args) => this.Close();` `form2.Show();` `this.Hide();` ? (In this order)

Comment: I get the error `Error CS7036 There is no argument given that corresponds to the required parameter 'fullnamereceived' of 'Form2.Form2(string)' FormSurveyOpdracht \Form2.cs 45 Active`
When I try to define `Form2 form2 = new Form2();` because it needs a string argument. (I normally get this string from Form1. This is to define a variable across 2 forms.

Comment: Yes, since you are a student it might be wise to tell yourself why you would do it in this order. Step 1: Creating an instance of the form (without this instance we cannot bind anything to the type itself So that would be `form2` not `Form2`). Step 2: binding the event on the instance of the form. Step 3: Hide the current form

Comment: Late to the party but let me throw in this: It's an x-y. You are probably trying to make some kind of Wizard? If so, you might want to present the steps as child Ui Elements _whithin one Form_ rather than a chain of forms.

Comment: Thanks for that. I did not make research about sub-forms / child UI. But this isn't going to be a wizard lol. Its a really simple "string nameVar = inputTextBox.Text" But if I will make a forms app in the future, I will not make this many forms, it doesn't look good if I do so.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You will have to bind an event on every form you open. Make sure you don't try to bind this event to the Type `Form2`, you cannot bind events on non instances of objects. You will need to bind it to `form2` the instance that you have made using the `= new Form2()`

```
using System;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Diagnostics;

namespace FormSurveyOpdracht
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void btnNext_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)  //When Next button is clicked:
        {
           //Rest of the Code

            Form2 form2 = new Form2(fullname);                  //Define a new form Form2, and send the variable fullname.
            form2.Closed += (sender, e) => this.Close(); //note that you bind it to the instance of `Form2` rather than the Type
            form2.Show();                                       //Show the Form2.
            this.Hide();                                        //Hide this Form (Form1)
        }
        private void Form1_FormClosing(object sender, FormClosingEventArgs e) //if the form is closed in an unexpected way, exit the whole application.
        {
            Application.Exit();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: This works. thanks. But since I do not define Form1 anywhere in the application, I added it to form3. Idk if that is optimal.

Comment: I think the FormClosing Event is no longer needed and you should remove it here. I assume it is and was even a problem. Calling Application.Exit will trigger a FormClosing on all open forms. I assume that ends up in a recursion problem.

Comment: Yes, I had already deleted that part. My question was, to do ` form2.Closed +=` ... I need to define the Form first doing `Form1 form1 = new Form1();`, but I did not use that anywhere in the code because it is already called at the beginning of the application, and I don't need to go back to it. 
Should I define it in Form3 (since it is the end of the application)